# How to setup publish with subset of data in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a large set of documents (1.7 million) in a collection. I would like to setup `Meteor.publish` in such a way that it accepts an argument/parameter so that it returns a very minimal data set. For e.g. argument could be a search value from the front-end.  Is it possible to pass arguments?

This is what I have so far.

```
//How do I pass front-end input in 'arg' here
Meteor.publish('postCodesTopic', function(arg){
    return PostCodes.find({postcode: arg});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following:

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('postCodesTopic', function(postcode) {
  return PostCodes.find({ postcode: postcode });
});
```

Client:

```
var postcode = 03885;
Meteor.subscribe('postCodesTopic', postcode);
```

The format of subscribe is `Meteor.subscribe(name, [arg1, arg2...], [callbacks])`, where arg1, arg2, etc. are the arguments for `Meteor.publish(name, function(arg1, arg2...))`